# Session Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho esta session normal:

```
foreach ($nofeatured_prods as $k) {
    $_SESSION['itens'][$k->id] = $k;
}
```

Como eu faço para atribuir de igual forma, porém, no codeigniter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use o método [set_userdata()](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#adding-session-data) da biblioteca de sessão do CI

Para atribuir faça:

```
$var = array('nome' => 'teste');
$this->session->set_userdata($var);
```

Ou ainda:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('chave', 'valor');
```

Para recupera faça:

```
$this->session->userdata('nome');
```

**Carregamento**

Para carregar essa biblioteca existem duas formas, a primeira é chamar ela apena onde será usada ou seja por demanda e a segunda deixar que o framework já carregue ela em todas as requests de forma automática.

Primeira forma:

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Segunda forma:

No arquivo config/autoload.php procure por `$autoload['libraries']` e adicione nesse array o elemento `session`.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session', 'database');
```

Comment: Neste caso @rray seria $this->session->set_userdata($k, ???);

Comment: Preciso setar todos os produtos que foram listados através desse array(), neste caso, o $_SESSION dava certo, mas em CI não dá certo. Porque não é nativa dela, tem de ser pelo $this->session

Comment: @AndréBaill `$k` é nome que vc vai buscar o segundo argumento é o valor.  Aconteceu algum erro?

Comment: @AndréBaill eu faria assim para guarda um array na sessão `$this->session->set_userdata('produtos', $arr);`

Comment: Sim, neste caso, fiz: $this->session->set_userdata('itens', $nofeatured_prods);